Rails app successfully deployed to Dokku droplet but still not available
I'm trying to deploy a rails app to a digitalocean dokku droplet. I ran all the necessary command on the droplet, then successfully pushed from local. I even added a domain to see if that would help.
Visiting the domain shows a "This site can’t be reached" error, and visiting the IP shows:

Welcome to nginx! If you see this page, the nginx web server is
successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.

What am I missing?
Below are the commands ran on the droplet. The app is named "playlistbuilder" and the database is named that as well:
dokku apps:create playlistbuilder
dokku plugin:install https://github.com/dokku/dokku-postgres.git postgres
dokku postgres:create playlistbuilder
dokku postgres:link playlistbuilder playlistbuilder
dokku postgres:link playlistbuilder playlistbuilder
dokku domains:add playlistbuilder playlist.creator

Below is the output from running git push dokku master - I removed a handful of bundler output because it didn't seem relevant to my question. It seems successful..:
$ git push dokku master
Enumerating objects: 13, done.
Counting objects: 100% (13/13), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 777 bytes | 777.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 7 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: -----> Cleaning up...
remote: -----> Building playlistbuilder from herokuish
remote: -----> Adding BUILD_ENV to build environment...
remote:        BUILD_ENV added successfully
remote:        -----> Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.
remote:               Detected buildpacks: ruby nodejs
remote:        -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Installing bundler 2.3.25
remote: -----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-3.1.2
remote:
remote:        ###### WARNING:
remote:
remote:        Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
remote:        Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
remote:        This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
remote:        In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at all.
remote:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile
remote:
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.3.25
remote:        Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin bundle install -j4
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Resolving dependencies..........
remote:        Using rake 13.2.1
remote:        Using concurrent-ruby 1.3.4
...
remote:        Using aws-sdk-kms 1.95.0
remote:        Fetching aws-sdk-s3 1.170.0
remote:        Installing rails_12factor 0.0.3
remote:        Installing aws-sdk-s3 1.170.0
remote:        Bundle complete! 26 Gemfile dependencies, 92 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups 'development' and 'test' were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`
remote:        Bundle completed (8.61s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote:        Removing aws-sdk-core (3.211.0)
remote:        Removing aws-sdk-s3 (1.169.0)
remote:        Removing timeout (0.4.1)
remote: -----> Installing node-v16.18.1-linux-x64
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        Asset precompilation completed (2.26s)
remote:        Cleaning assets
remote:        Running: rake assets:clean
remote: -----> Detecting rails configuration
remote:
remote:        ###### WARNING:
remote:
remote:        Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
remote:        Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
remote:        This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
remote:        In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at all.
remote:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile
remote:
remote:        ###### WARNING:
remote:
remote:        There is a more recent Ruby version available for you to use:
remote:
remote:        3.1.6
remote:
remote:        The latest version will include security and bug fixes. We always recommend
remote:        running the latest version of your minor release.
remote:
remote:        Please upgrade your Ruby version.
remote:
remote:        For all available Ruby versions see:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes
remote:
remote:        ###### WARNING:
remote:
remote:        No Procfile detected, using the default web server.
remote:        We recommend explicitly declaring how to boot your server process via a Procfile.
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server
remote:
remote:
remote:        -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Default types for  -> rake, console, web
remote: -----> Releasing playlistbuilder...
remote: -----> Checking for predeploy task
remote:        No predeploy task found, skipping
remote: -----> Checking for release task
remote:        No release task found, skipping
remote: =====> Processing deployment checks
remote:        No CHECKS file found. Simple container checks will be performed.
remote:        For more efficient zero downtime deployments, create a CHECKS file. See https://dokku.com/docs/deployment/zero-downtime-deploys/ for examples
remote: -----> Deploying playlistbuilder via the docker-local scheduler...
remote: -----> Deploying web (count=1)
remote:        Attempting pre-flight checks (web.1)
remote:        Waiting for 10 seconds (web.1)
remote:        Default container check successful (web.1)
remote:        Scheduling old container shutdown in 60 seconds (web.1)
remote: =====> Triggering early nginx proxy rebuild
remote: -----> Ensuring network configuration is in sync for playlistbuilder
remote: -----> Configuring playlist.creator...(using built-in template)
remote: -----> Configuring playlistbuilder.packer-6481b5fa-f32f-c6ab-b44d-a2621ac2dcee...(using built-in template)
remote: -----> Creating http nginx.conf
remote:        Reloading nginx
remote: -----> Running post-deploy
remote:  !     Detected IPv4 domain name with nginx proxy enabled.
remote:  !     Ensure the default nginx site is removed before continuing.
remote: -----> Ensuring network configuration is in sync for playlistbuilder
remote: -----> Configuring playlist.creator...(using built-in template)
remote: -----> Configuring playlistbuilder.packer-6481b5fa-f32f-c6ab-b44d-a2621ac2dcee...(using built-in template)
remote: -----> Creating http nginx.conf
remote:        Reloading nginx
remote: -----> Renaming containers
remote:        Found previous container(s) (2fbdab2249ce) named playlistbuilder.web.1
remote:        Renaming container (2fbdab2249ce) playlistbuilder.web.1 to playlistbuilder.web.1.1730987359
remote:        Renaming container playlistbuilder.web.1.upcoming-25604 (a33e595155ee) to playlistbuilder.web.1
remote: -----> Checking for postdeploy task
remote:        No postdeploy task found, skipping
remote: -----> Shutting down old containers in 60 seconds
remote: =====> Application deployed:
remote:        http://playlist.creator
remote:        http://playlistbuilder.packer-6481b5fa-f32f-c6ab-b44d-a2621ac2dcee
remote:
To 178.128.157.11:playlistbuilder
   a7e10a0..5045835  master -> master

Versions:
Ruby 3.1.2
Dokku 0.30.6
Ubuntu 22.04

This question is similar to: Nginx page displaying instead of home page (Digital Ocean - LEMP). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thanks for bringing that to my attention - the second answer solved the issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/78882862/5161457. Will paste it below, because while the error message is the same, it's such a general message that I wouldn't have assumed the two issues were related. Thanks for your help :)

Thanks you @dbugger for pointing me in the right direction. @Edmund's answer to this question was the solution to my issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78882862/5161457
Remove the default site if it exists:
sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

Test your Nginx configuration:
sudo nginx -t

If the test passes, reload Nginx:
sudo systemctl reload nginx

Then retry in 10 mins.

Why the hell Dokku wouldn't do this automatically or at the very least the docs wouldn't point to this? So far Dokku is very lacking on contextualizing at deploy time, it's very frustrating.
